# Updated a new release of my app to the play store, but users are not notified of the update

Tags: android, google-play

I have been releasing some updates for my App the latest is version 1.0.1. When I check the play store I see that version 1.0.1 has been published. However, my users have not been notified of the updates. I have 3 different users who are testing this for me.

When I check the devices they are still using the previous version of my App which is 1.0.0. I have used the same keystore to publish the release so they shouldn't be any problem there.

And in my developer console I can see the release has been published and is in production.

This is my first App, so just wondering if I am doing something wrong.

I was thinking that the play store would handle this for you, and just wondering do I have to configure something?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Did your testers updated the application from play store?

Comment: Sometimes it takes up to 3-4 hours to publish a new version. Did you waited enough time for it?

Comment: I think Farooq is right. I installed from Android Studio on the 3 devices and not from the Play Store.